# Statements about a system of equations true/false

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following question here:

> Consider the homogeneous system $Ax=0$ of $m$ equations for $n>m$ unknowns. Which is the following statements is *false*?
>
> $(A)$ $x=0$ is the only solution
>
> $(B)$ There are always infinitely many distinct solutions.
>
> $(C)$ The general solutions has at least $n-m$ free variables (free parameters).
>
> $(D)$ If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two solutions, so is $x_1+tx_2$ for any $t \epsilon \mathbb{R}. $
>
> $(E)$ If $x_1$ solves $Ax=0$ and $x_2$ solves $Ax=b$, then $x_2+tx_1$ solves $Ax=b$, $t \epsilon \mathbb{R}$.

The answer is supposed to be $(A)$. It makes sense since a homogeneous system does not require the trivial solution  for there to be a solution to the homogeneous system of equations **(I assume my reasoning is right?)** but why are the other choices true?

I think $(B)$ is true because solutions to a system of equations can be parametrized in infinitely many ways so hence it is true. **Is that correct?**

I am not sure why $(C)$ and $(D)$ are true though. Can someone please explain? Thanks!

Comment: ($D$) follows from ($E$) considering $b=0$. $(A)$ is false because otherwise $A$ were invertible.

Comment: But why is $(E)$ true? How are you able to express the solution as a linear combination like that?

Comment: Knowing the fact that matrices are always linear, $A(x_1+tx_2)=Ax_1+t\cdot Ax_2=?$

Comment: $0+b$? Because those are the solutions to the given system?

Comment: $0+t\cdot b$. Yes according to the if statement in the proposition $E$.

Comment: Did you mean to write "$A(x_2+tx_1)=Ax_2+t\cdot Ax_1=?$" instead?

Comment: Yeah sorry for that.

Comment: @YadatiKiran what did you mean by " $(A)$ is false because otherwise $A$ were invertible." ? The wording is a little confusing.

Comment: $Ax=b$ in general has a unique solution iff $A$ is invertible i.e. $Ax=b\implies x=A^{-1}b$ if $A^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!